# Pandas: Find rows where last five columns satisfy condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, `df`, that has 100 columns.  The last 5 of those columns take on binary values.  I want to find all rows where the the last five columns look like: 0, 1, 0, 1, 1.

I could do this by `and`ing conditions like:

`df[(df.col95 == 0) & (df.col96 == 1) ...]` but I'm sure there's a better way and I don't want to name the columns.

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: tuple(row[-5:]) == (0, 1, 0, 1, 1))]
```

But I get an `Unalignable Boolean series provided as indexer` error.  Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `merge` here

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame([[0,1,0,1,1]],columns=df.columns[-5:]))
```